# How to remove a portion from a 3d plane?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, geometry, visualization

I'm plotting in matplotlib. I want to remove a circle on the planes where they intersect with the catenoid surfaces. It's ok to have the intersection hard coded, as long as it looks fine visually.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Parametric equations for the catenoid surface
def catenoid(u, v, a=1):
    x = a * np.cosh(u/a) * np.cos(v)
    y = a * np.cosh(u/a) * np.sin(v)
    z = u
    return x, y, z

# Generate u and v values
u = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
u, v = np.meshgrid(u, v)

# Create the figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d", computed_zorder=False)
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=(6, 4, 3))
ax.set_axis_off()

# Plot the first catenoid surface without gridlines
x1, y1, z1 = catenoid(u, v)
surf1 = ax.plot_surface(x1, y1, z1, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='grey', alpha=0.5, vmin=-2, vmax=2)

# Plot the second catenoid surface with an offset along the y-axis without gridlines
x2, y2, z2 = catenoid(u, v)
x2_offset = x2 + 8  # Adjust the offset value as needed
surf2 = ax.plot_surface(x2_offset, y2, z2, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='grey', alpha=0.5, vmin=-2, vmax=2)


# Plot the first plane with top and bottom colors of the first catenoid surface
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 13, 100), np.linspace(-5, 5, 100))
zz = yy * 0 - 2
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, zorder=-1, alpha=0.5, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none', vmin=-2, vmax=2)
zz = yy * 0 + 2
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, zorder=1, alpha=0.5, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none', vmin=-2, vmax=2)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Currently, it looks like:
[image]

I want to get rid of the grey parts, so the plane is not covering the catenoid openings:
[image]

Comment: Is this what you want? https://pasteboard.co/99emAYiRkf7r.png. Cause I'm not so sure about your desired output.

Comment: yes! how did you do that?

Comment: OK, I will post an answer.

Comment: The same parts need to be removed on the bottom plane as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created two circle masks for the planes. Because your graph is symmetrical, for the planes `z=2` and `z=-2`, they have the same mask.
When generating the x,y coordinates of the plane, I increased the amount of data to reduce the burrs of the generated mask.

Here are the codes after the line `surf2 = ax.plot_surface...`, I have added some comments:

```
# Defin x, y of the plane 
plane_2_x = np.linspace(-5, 13, 1000)
plane_2_y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)

# Calculate the radius of the circles
radius = np.max(x1)

# Calculate all the distances of the points in the plane to the center of the circle 
dist_from_center_1 = np.sqrt((plane_2_x.reshape(-1, 1) - 0)**2 + (plane_2_y.reshape(1, -1)-0)**2) # center is [0, 0]
mask_1 = dist_from_center_1<=radius # Calculate the first mask
dist_from_center_2 = np.sqrt((plane_2_x.reshape(-1, 1) - 8)**2 + (plane_2_y.reshape(1, -1)-0)**2) # center is [8, 0]
mask_2 = dist_from_center_2<=radius # Calculate the second mask

# Plot the first plane with top and bottom colors of the first catenoid surface
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(plane_2_x, plane_2_y)
zz = yy * 0 - 2
zz[np.logical_or(mask_1.T, mask_2.T)] = np.nan # Apply the mask for the plane z=-2
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, zorder=-1, alpha=0.5, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none', vmin=-2, vmax=2)
zz = yy * 0 + 2
zz[np.logical_or(mask_1.T, mask_2.T)] = np.nan # Apply the mask for the plane z=2
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, zorder=-1, alpha=0.5, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none', vmin=-2, vmax=2)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Here is result :
[image]